# bug state change in time

Tags: mysql, time

I have been working for a while on a mysql query that will give me bug state in particular time (bug_id, bug_severity, resolution, rank, etc...) I'm working with bugzilla 3.42 database, and I have all columns that I need there, in different tables, and I created query that will give me what state was changed in some particular time (for example, column bug_when is 03-03-2014, and only bug_severity column is filled, others are null). This is my code:

```
  select
ba.bug_id,  ba.bug_when,
case when fd.name='bug_id' then removed end as bug_id,
case when fd.name = 'product' then removed end as product,
case when fd.name = 'version' then removed end as version,
case when fd.name = 'bug_status' then removed end as status,
case when fd.name = 'resolution' then removed end as resolution,
case when fd.name = 'bug_severity' then removed end as severity,
case when fd.name = 'component' then removed end as component,
case when fd.name = 'rank' then removed end as rank,
case when fd.name = 'rank_number' then removed end as rank_number,
case when fd.name = 'occurence' then removed end as occurence,
case when fd.name = 'responsible_team' then removed end as responsible_team
from bugs_activity as ba
inner join fielddefs as fd on ba.fieldid=fd.id  
where fd.name in ('bug_id', 'product', 'version', 'bug_status', 'resolution',       'bug_severity', 'component', 'rank', 'rank_number', 'occurence', 'cf_responsible_team')
order by ba.bug_id
```

But, I need to have query that will give me all his previous state in some time. For example, on 04-04-2014, all my fields needs to be filled with his state in that period. I have in bugs table his last state, and table bugs_activity, where I have the time when bug change some of his states, and I have added and removed state. 
Here is bugzilla schema, I have all tables from there
http://www.ravenbrook.com/tool/bugzilla-schema/?action=single&version=3.4&view=View+schema

Any help?

Comment: Can you clarify? I think you are saying you require a query to capture the state of a bug record at a particular point in time. Is that correct?

Comment: In bugs_activity table, for example, when I run "select rows", I have for example 10 rows with bug_id=1, different bug_when values, and for each value there is saved some different activity for bug, for example, added ASSIGNED removed NEW, and next row is added UIMode added ClientA and so on... What it need is to list every that bug_when for all bug_id's and see what state is changed(if state for rank is not changed in that time, I need to write in that field his previous state- his rank wasn't changed, and I simply need to write his previous state of rank... it's the same with other columns)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture a snapshot of a bug's state at a particular time, you can add a `WHERE` clause to choose a subset of the `bugs_activity` rows.

Try adding this to your `where` clause in your sample query.

```
   AND ba.bug_when < '2014-04-04` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This will ignore all `bugs_activity` rows after midnight on the day following the date you specify. That should present the state of each bug as of the day you mention.

You may need also to filter other tables in the schema in a similar way.

Comment: The thing is that I need to have all values in every column (I don't need any null value), for every bug_when time. If in first column I have value normal for bug severity, and it's not changed until my bug was completely closed, I need for every bug_when to write noral as his bug_severity. If it was changed in some time, from that moment to the end it needs to be his new value